# MYSQL table displaying cut off rows

Tags: mysql

So I have a table that is storing data that I believe has hidden characters in it.

When i do a select * from table; I get the following data

```
+----------+----------------------+-----------+-----------------+---------------------+--------------------+------+-----------+
| account  | ip                   | proxy     | proxyip         | customer            | SalesStaffInitials | LCR  | realproxy |
+----------+----------------------+-----------+-----------------+---------------------+--------------------+------+-----------+
 | XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX | XXXXXX Network Inc. |  XX                | NULL | proxyXXX
+----------+----------------------+-----------+-----------------+---------------------+--------------------+------+-----------+
```

as you can see the first thing that is being shown is the column 'proxyip' even though it is the 4th column.

I've tried using trim() to get rid of leading white space. I've also tried the following query to try to get rid of hidden characters:

UPDATE customers SET realproxy = TRIM(REPLACE(proxy, CONVERT(char(160) USING utf8), ' '));

Also if it helps when i export the file to a CSV, the first 3 columns are on 1 row and then the rest of the columns are on another row.

Has anyone seen anything like this before? Let me know if I need to include anything else, thank you.

edit1: I just did a select on each column and it the only column that looks off is proxy.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like you have a carriage return or newline chraracter at the beginning of the value in the `proxyip` column.

To find out what that character is, I would use the HEX function to get a hexadecimal representation of the value `SELECT HEX(proxyip) FROM ...`

Newline character is `x'0A'`, carriage return is `x'0D'`.  Or you may have some other control character in there. (e.g. tab character is `x'09'`.

If you want to remove all occurrences of those characters,

```
 SELECT     REPLACE(REPLACE(proxyip,'\n',''),'\r','')  AS new_proxyip
      , HEX(REPLACE(REPLACE(proxyip,'\n',''),'\r','')) AS hex_new_proxyip
   FROM ...
```

The REPLACE function can be used in an UPDATE statement as well...

```
 UPDATE ...
    SET mycol = REPLACE(REPLACE( mycol ,'\n',''),'\r','')
```